# PythonGtk : expand NoteBook to fill the rest of my window

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to resize my window using Python Gtk3, but I need to expand the Notebook object to fill the main window.
How could I make the notebook fill the rest of the window?

Like this:
[image: Like this]

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk


class SearchDialog(Gtk.Dialog):

  def __init__(self, parent):
      Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "Something", parent,
          Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL, buttons=(
          Gtk.STOCK_NEW, Gtk.ResponseType.OK,
          Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL))

      self.set_default_size(400, 600)

      box = self.get_content_area()

      label = Gtk.Label("Insert text you want to search for:")
      box.add(label)

#        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
#        box.add(self.entry)

      self.main_area = Gtk.Stack()
      self.main_area.set_transition_type(Gtk.StackTransitionType.SLIDE_LEFT_RIGHT)

      self.main_area.set_transition_duration(1000)

      self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
      self.main_area.add_titled(self.entry, "entry_name", "Entry Url")

      self.labelS = Gtk.Label()
      self.label_txt = """<big><i> label here</i></big>"""
      self.labelS.set_markup(self.label_txt)
      self.labelS.set_line_wrap(True)
      self.main_area.add_titled(self.labelS, "label_name", "How Scan will Start")

      self.our_stackSwitcher = Gtk.StackSwitcher()
      self.our_stackSwitcher.set_stack(self.main_area)

      box.add(self.our_stackSwitcher)
      box.add(self.main_area)

      self.show_all()


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Desktop app title")

        self.set_default_size(1000, 648)
        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.add(vbox)
        Hbox1 = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox.add(Hbox1)
        Hbox2 = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox.add(Hbox2)
        Hbox3 = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox.add(Hbox3)
        Hbox4 = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        vbox.add(Hbox4)

        main_menu_bar = Gtk.MenuBar()
#################################################################################
        #drop down the menu
        file_menu1 = Gtk.Menu()
        file_menu1_dropdown = Gtk.MenuItem("File")

        #File menu Items
        file_new = Gtk.MenuItem("New Scan")
        file_save = Gtk.MenuItem("Save History")
        file_exit = Gtk.MenuItem("Exit")

        file_menu1_dropdown.set_submenu(file_menu1)
        file_menu1.append(file_new)
        file_new.connect("activate", self.Onclick_new)
        file_menu1.append(file_save)
        file_save.connect("activate", self.Onclick_save)
        file_menu1.append(Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem())
        file_menu1.append(file_exit)
        file_exit.connect("activate",self.Onclick_exit)

        #add the menu to the main menu bar
        main_menu_bar.append(file_menu1_dropdown)
###################################################################################
        #drop down the menu
        file_menu2 = Gtk.Menu()
        file_menu2_dropdown = Gtk.MenuItem("Scan")

        #File menu Items
        file_edit = Gtk.MenuItem("Edit")
        file_cancel = Gtk.MenuItem("Cancel")

        file_menu2_dropdown.set_submenu(file_menu2)
        file_menu2.append(file_edit)
        file_edit.connect("activate", self.Onclick_edit)
        file_menu2.append(file_cancel)
        file_cancel.connect("activate", self.Onclick_cancel)


        #add the menu to the main menu bar
        main_menu_bar.append(file_menu2_dropdown)
###################################################################################
        #drop down the menu
        file_menu3 = Gtk.Menu()
        file_menu3_dropdown = Gtk.MenuItem("Help")

        #File menu Items
        file_mode = Gtk.MenuItem("Mode")
        file_about = Gtk.MenuItem("About")

        file_menu3_dropdown.set_submenu(file_menu3)
        file_menu3.append(file_mode)
        file_mode.connect("activate", self.Onclick_mode)
        file_menu3.append(file_about)
        file_about.connect("activate", self.Onclick_about)


        #add the menu to the main menu bar
        main_menu_bar.append(file_menu3_dropdown)
###################################################################################
        ## ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ##
        Hbox1.pack_start(main_menu_bar , True, True, 0)

        label1_Hbox2 = Gtk.Label(" i am label 1 of Horizental box 2")
        Hbox2.pack_start(label1_Hbox2 , True, True, 0)
        label2_Hbox2 = Gtk.Label(" i am label 2 of Horizental box 2")
        Hbox2.pack_start(label2_Hbox2, True, True, 0)

        self.notebook1 = Gtk.Notebook()
        Hbox3.pack_start(self.notebook1, True, True, 0)
        self.notebook2 = Gtk.Notebook()
        Hbox3.pack_start(self.notebook2, True, True, 0)
##################################################################################################
        self.page1 = Gtk.Box()
        self.page1.set_border_width(3)
        self.label = Gtk.Label('label Number 1-------')
        self.page1.add(self.label)
        self.label2 = Gtk.Label('label Number 2 should appear in next line')
        self.page1.add(self.label2)
        self.notebook1.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label('Tab Pane 1 panel 1'))
###################################################################################################
        self.page1 = Gtk.Box()

        self.notebook2.append_page(self.page1, Gtk.Label('Tab Pane 1 panel 2'))

        self.page2 = Gtk.Box()
        self.notebook2.append_page(self.page2, Gtk.Label('Tab Pane 2 panel 2'))

    def Onclick_new(self, widget):
      dialog = SearchDialog(self)
      response = dialog.run()
      if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        self.label.set_text(dialog.entry.get_text())
      dialog.destroy()

    def Onclick_save(self, widget):
        print("Save clicked")

    def Onclick_exit(self, widget):
        print("exit clicked")
        Gtk.main_quit()
    def Onclick_edit(self, widget):
        print("Edit clicked")
    def Onclick_cancel(self, widget):
        print("Cancel clicked")
    def Onclick_mode(self, widget):
        print("Mode of use clicked")
    def Onclick_about(self, widget):
        print("About clicked")

#cssProvider = Gtk.CssProvider()
#cssProvider.load_from_path('gtkStyledButtonTest.css')
#screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
#styleContext = Gtk.StyleContext()
#styleContext.add_provider_for_screen(screen, cssProvider,
#                                     Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Currently it is quiet unclear what you mean, so could you please use paint (or something else) to make a image showing what you want to achieve?

Comment: @B8vrede :  check the image how should appear the Notebook with me

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to have the Notebook fill all the remaining height? In that case it is simple just change the constructor to this `self.notebook1 = Gtk.Notebook(vexpand=True)`. That will tell the Notebook to fill any space that remains in the vertical direction.

Comment: I edited your post. As you were warned on your previous question, please do not tag questions with irrelevant tags. Also, I have attempted to clarify what you're asking, but your question was very unclear, so I can't be sure it is correct.